# no matching function for call to (Classes, c++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic, constructor

Im junior in C++ and Im making programm that show some data by making conversion to method in my class. It is not really done yet, but when I create a class object it says to me "no matching function for call to" at the line "Passport Info". Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Passport {
private:
    int _size = 6;
    std::string* class_people;
    std::string* class_birth;
    std::string people[6] = {
        "bro1", "bro2", "bro3", "bro4", "bro5", "bro6"
    };
    std::string birth[6] = { "1995", "1994", "1996", "1994", "2001", "1990" };

public:
    Passport(std::string people, std::string birth)
    {
        class_people = new string[_size];
        class_birth = new string[_size];

        for (int ix = 0; ix < _size; ix++) {
            class_people[ix] = people[ix];
            class_birth[ix] = birth[ix];
        }
    }

    void show_data()
    {
        for (int px = 0; px < _size; px++) {
            cout << class_people[px] << endl;
            cout << class_birth[px] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    Passport Info;
    Info.show_data();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
};
```

Also I want to make pointers to my string variables at private section of Passport class for use in constructor but how? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to construct an instance of `Passport` without passing it any arguments you need to define a default constructor for it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: make that an answer.

Comment: Prefer `std::vector<std::string>` to `new String[]`. Take parameters by `const &`. Make your private defaults `const`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Thank you, it worked. :)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Okay, I will do. Im just new so its not easy to remember everything. :)

Comment: Don't use `std::string*`. Use `std::string` (no pointer). C++ is not Java.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: that doesn't quite apply, since he's using arrays. `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @MooingDuck: You are right, thanks. I suppose I just saw the asterisk and my *"Java programmer is writing Java in C++"* alarm went off! :) `std::vector<std::string>` is the way to go, or `std::array<std::string>` if the size is known before the program starts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Passport` class doesn't have a default constructor which `Passport Info;` is trying to call.

Either add a default constructor to your `Passport` class or add some parameters to  `Passport Info;` For example:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    Passport Info("Vladimir", "1995");
    Info.show_data();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
};
```